# How Synchronous fallbacks works for Asynchronous calls in Hystrix?

Tags: java, hystrix, fallback, circuit-breaker

Let's say I have the following piece of code with Hystrix circuit breaker and fallback enabled:

```
@Component
public class MyServiceProxy {

 @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "syncFallback")
 public Future <MyClass> asyncCall() {

  return new AsyncResult <MyClass> () {
   @Override
   public MyClass invoke() {
    return new MyClass();
   }
  };
 }

 private MyClass syncFallback() {
  return new MyClass();
 }
}
```

The service class is something like this:

```
@Service
public class UseMyService {

 @Inject
 public MyServiceProxy myServiceProxy;

 public void getResults() {

/* 

 In the case of a fallback the fallback method will
 return a non future result and how does this piece of code not fail ?
 I expected the below call to fail when fallback method is called.

*/

Future <MyClass> myClassFutureResponse = myServiceProxy.asyncCall();

  try {

   MyClass actualResponse = myClassFutureResponse.get();

  } catch (Exception e) {

  }

 }
}
```

This is my question:

1. How does sync fallback for async calls in Hystrix works as expected ? I know it is allowed and it works.

In my understanding the calling method would expect an async result(Future) but the fallback would return a non future response and calling get shouldn't be allowed and the code should throw exception but apparently it doesn't happen and it works as expected(without any casting).

Any details/insight on helping me understand this concept would be great!